# How to store image as encoded string in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to convert image to string and save it inside *MongoDB*. I also want to decode it later.

I'm using only *Express*, *MongoDB* and *ReactJS* and I don't want to upload the image file on my server, they'll be user photo.

Comment: Maybe you want to encode image to base64, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/8828489. I think it is not best way to store image by base64 in mongodb. You can try other service to store image or store it on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to encode image to **base64**, please refer [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript/20285053#20285053).

#### Issues

I think it is *not a good way* to store an image by *base64* in MongoDB. I think it will add overhead.

You can try *another service* to store image or *upload* it on your server. In MongoDB, we only store image **URI/URL**, that will reduce overhead.

There are some services allow you uploads image free with APIs:

- [Imgur](https://api.imgur.com/): You can refer [Build an Image Uploader with Imgur API and JavaScript](https://ctrlq.org/code/20526-javascript-image-uploader)
- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/):  You can refer [Upload Files to Firebase Storage with JavaScript](https://time2hack.com/2017/10/upload-files-to-firebase-storage-with-javascript/)
- [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/)
- [Upload.im](http://uploads.im/apidocs)
- [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/)

Comment: Thank you , its first time im trying to do such thing , also i dont like API from any one , bug companies who give such service make everything easier and i believe they are not helping and just make everyone lazy . i want to make in on my own . if base 64 is not good idea do you know how to handle image from front end to express and then store images somewhere on my server ?